# How can I use the ModelChoiceField in a list with the same values ​in the OPTION and VALUE OPTION e select?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

How can I use the ModelChoiceField in a list with the same values ​​in the OPTION and VALUE OPTION e select?

I need queryset to return to select the same values ​​for the list and VALUE of the options

Model

```
class Produto(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    referencia = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome + ' - ' + self.referencia
```

Form

```
class FormItem(forms.Form):

        produto = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, label='Produto', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'placeholder': 'Produto', 'class': 'input select2'}))

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(FormFaturaItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['produto'].queryset = Produto.objects.all()
```

Form result

```
<select>
<option value="dd3e2aff-924d-4945-9929-3d37b81b3ebb">KIT MATERNIDADE  - 9049</option>
</select>
```

Expected result

```
 <select>
    <option value="KIT MATERNIDADE  - 9049">KIT MATERNIDADE  - 9049</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: The option `value` should be the primary key (`uuid`) for that model. Have you tried changing `FormItem` to a `forms.ModelForm`? If none of this will work can you give more details on what you're wanting to accomplish?

Comment: I wish the result to be described in 'Expected result'

Comment: Yes but why? Can you share the view that this form is POST'ing to?

Comment: The form is not a post.

This is the initial date to load a list of items before submitting the form.

This list is loaded from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
produto = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), label='Produto', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'placeholder': 'Produto', 'class': 'input select2'}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    a = []
    for i in Produto.objects.all():
        a.append((i.nome, i.nome))

    self.fields['produto'].choices = tuple(a)
```